# I have a time series data, I am trying to identify blocks which satisfies the pattern of two consecutive rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe like this (click on image).
I want to find the difference in time between false->true to true->false and get a list of all such values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8CtH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zVhm.png)

so the output list should be like:
[2,3]

Answer (score 0):

You can take the consecutive difference between rows where the following row is the same as the preceding row. Something like:

```
# get df
df = pd.DataFrame(2 * [False] + 2 * [True] + 3 * [False] + 3 * [True])
df.loc[df['value'], 'grouped_value'] = (df['value'] != df['value'].shift(1)).cumsum()
#output
 value    grouped_value
0  False  NaN
1  False  NaN
2   True  2.0
3   True  2.0
4  False  NaN
5  False  NaN
6  False  NaN
7   True  4.0
8   True  4.0
9   True  4.0
df.groupby('grouped_value').count()
#output
  0
1     
2.0  2
4.0  3
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. but I need the difference in 'time period' like in hours or days.. I actually have a time series data actually (shown in the second figure), I need to find the time intervals when the signal has started deviating from base value (rising) and settled back to base value... I need to find the time intervals for all such deviations within a given time range.. that is the background.. @ClimbingTheCurve